# How to calculate padding-top in % of the given div relative to its parent div

Tags: css, responsive-design, padding, scaling, responsiveness

**Problem: I want to add padding-top in % to all list items** (because I need to move the text a little down and also need all elements to be scalable), **[here is jsfiddle code](https://jsfiddle.net/hg2cfqhk/)**

Height works fine. In order to calculate height I calculated the percentage of li height(which originally was 40px) relative to its parent ul(which was 400px). 40px out of 400px = 10%. It seems to work fine after that total ul height is still equal to 400px. (box has height of 53.33vw bacause 400px is 53.33% of 750px).

**But the problem is with calculating padding-top in %.** In order to calculate padding-top (which was 8px) I needed to calculate 8px out of 400px(400px is the height of the parent ul) = 2%, and as in fixed layout I subtracted those 2% from height (10% so height was now 8%). But after that the total ul height is equal to 470px. How to calculate padding-top in % so that height of ul still will be 400px? I need to preserve those 400px which was the original height of the ul, after adding the padding-top in % the height of ul becomes 470px which is not correct.

HTML:

```
<div class="box">
<ul class="list">
<li>Item 1</li>
<li>Item 2</li>
<li>Item 3</li>
<li>Item 4</li>
<li>Item 5</li>
<li>Item 6</li>
<li>Item 7</li>
<li>Item 8</li>
<li>Item 9</li>
<li>Item 10</li>
</ul>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
body {
    line-height: 1;
}

/* THIS IS MY CODE*/

.box {
    margin:0 auto;
    width:100%;
    max-width:750px;
    height:53.33vw;
    max-height:400px;
}

ul.list {
    padding: 0;
    width:100%;
    height:100%;
    background:green;
    list-style-type:none;
    text-align:center;
    font-size:3vw;
}

ul li:nth-child(odd) {
    height:8%;
    width:interit;
    padding-top:2%;
    background:grey;
}

ul li:nth-child(even) {
    height:8%;
    width:interit;
    padding-top:2%;
    background:red;
}
```

Comment: I'm not sure I grasp what you're after, but you might try `box-sizing`. Anyway, you are aware of the pitfalls with `padding-top` in percentages?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

This is because `padding` and `margin` in `%` gets calculated from `width`, not `height` as you desire.

From the [spec for padding](http://www.w3.org/TR/2011/REC-CSS2-20110607/box.html#padding-properties)

> Unlike margin properties, values for padding values cannot be negative. Like margin properties, percentage values for padding properties refer to the width of the generated box's containing block.

And from the [spec for margin](http://www.w3.org/TR/2011/REC-CSS2-20110607/box.html#margin-properties)

> The percentage is calculated with respect to the width of the generated box's containing block. Note that this is true for 'margin-top' and 'margin-bottom' as well. If the containing block's width depends on this element, then the resulting layout is undefined in CSS 2.1.
>   This is also how you can create aspect-ratio locked divs in HTML since you can calculate `height` from `width` using `padding-top` with a percentage value.

A solution for you would be to use [CSS calc](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/CSS/calc), it has good [browser support](http://caniuse.com/#search=calc) and fixes your issue in quite a simple manner. The only downside here is that it doesn't calculate the `padding-top` in `%` but you simply cannot calculate `padding-top` in `%` from the `height` of the element unless you use javascript.

If you **don't absolutely require** the `padding-top: 2%;` I would suggest the below solution.

Your CSS would look like this

```
ul.list li {
    height: calc(10% - 8px);
    padding-top: 8px;
}
```

This would give all `ul.list li` items a height of `10% - 8px` and that `8px` is then also used as value for `padding-top` which would basically make a perfect `10%` again.

You can write your selectors in a different style too, I used `ul.list li` here as the main selector to just select all `li` elements but you have `:nth-child(odd)` and `:nth-child(even)` selectors.

You wrote duplicate properties on these selectors while the only difference is their `background` property.

I would strongly recommend to avoid duplication as much as possible as you'll definitely forget to change *both* properties sometimes, instead change your CSS to something like this:

```
/*shared properties in a general selector*/
ul.list li {
    width: inherit;
    height: calc(10% - 8px);
    padding-top: 8px;
    background: grey;
}

/*if rule is not applied, use ul.list instead of just ul*/
ul li:nth-child(even) {
    background: red;
}
```

This even removes the need for `ul li:nth-child(odd)` since this can also be part of the shared styling and then be *overwritten* by the more specific `ul li:nth-child(even)` selector.

#### Another way

Another way of doing this instead of relying on `%` values is to use either `em` or `rem` values - they work by scaling based on font size.

More reading

- [web-design-basics-rem-vs-em-vs-px-sizing-elements-in-css](https://www.futurehosting.com/blog/web-design-basics-rem-vs-em-vs-px-sizing-elements-in-css/)
- [the-ems-have-it-proportional-media-queries-ftw](http://blog.cloudfour.com/the-ems-have-it-proportional-media-queries-ftw/)
- [ems-rems](https://css-tricks.com/rems-ems/)
- [confused-rems-ems](https://css-tricks.com/confused-rem-em/)

Basically, `rem` is *always* relative to the `root element` which is the `<html>` element.

Setting a font-size on the `<html>` element will define the value of `1rem` in CSS, if no `font-size` is set then the browser default (usually `16px` will be used).

```
html {
    font-size: 16px; /*1rem is now 16px*/
}
```

When you define the `font-size` like above with a value of `16px` then `0.5rem` will equal `8px` - why is this interesting? It's scaleable! But by different means.

When you now apply a media query and change the `font-size` to something bigger or smaller, everything using `rem` will scale proportionally (you'd have to set `font-size` of the `<html>` element ofcourse.)

Now `em` is a bit different, it's relative to it's own `font-size` but since this get's inherited from it's *parent element* automatically (if `font-size` is set in `em` or `%` that is) it's basically relative to the parent.

If we take the last CSS example

```
html {
    font-size: 16px; /* 1rem = 16px, 1em = 16px */
}

body > div { /*every direct div of body tag*/
    font-size: 0.5em; /*8px*/
    font-size: 0.5rem; /*8px*/
}

body > div > div { /*every second level nested div*/
    font-size: 0.5em; /*4px*/
    font-size: 0.5rem; /*8px*/
}
```

Basically, since `em` is sort-of relative to it's parent size the font-size decreases more when you scale in `em` - this is potentially dangerous since if you change your structure and add a container that slightly reduces font-size on most of the page this could have a bigger effect than you think.

With that out of the way, technically `em` and `rem` are the best ways to scale `padding` and `margin` on elements according to the `font-size` property.

An example for your container could look like this:

```
ul.list li {
    height: 8%;
    padding-top: 0.5rem; /*if font-size is 16px, this will be 8px*/
}
```

In terms of scalability this will work when you change the font-size to something else on a mobile device for instance.

It doesn't provide a solution to your question but it does provide an answer and your best alternative when talking about scalability, I hope this helps you in your quest for that :)

Comment: Using 'height: calc(10% - 8px);' achieves the desired result (ul height is 400px) and thank you for that. But still the padding-top is not scalable. It would be cool if EVERYTHING was scalable. When scaling down the page that 8px will still remain 8px while the rest of the page will scale down.

Comment: Ok, so jQuery is the answer. What about using that *css calc* in margin-top and margin-bottom will this work like in the example of the padding above ?

Comment: @ania_piszko updated answer with some scalability alternatives using `em` and `rem` with some posts explaining how it works

Comment: Can those *rem* and *em* be applied to border as well ?

Comment: I meant border-top and bodrer-bottom beacause in borers left and right, as well as in paddingleft and right and margin left-and right, width CAN be specified in % in relation to its parent, this is top and bottom which is causing the probem

Comment: @ania_piszko everywhere you can use a `px` value you can also use `em` and `rem`

Answer (score 0):

The CSS `box-sizing: border-box;` property will make the width maximum and everything else calculated towards inside.

Good in combination with the `width:100%;` when in tight areas

Learn more: https://www.w3schools.com/cssref/css3_pr_box-sizing.asp